# How can I this Implement logic into method

Tags: javascript

Trying to implement this logic into a certain method but it ends up messing up the javascript.The idea is to implement the logic below into the code.

```
function onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: Topic: ', message.destinationName, '. Payload: ', message.payloadString, '. QoS: ', message.qos);
//  console.log(message);

    var status = message.payloadString;
    var indicator = message.destinationName;
```

When the logic below is inserted everything goes haywire. I need help seeing the problem....

```
    /*This is the logic that messes up the code */
if(message.payloadString == "ON")
{

if(message.destinationName == /data/read/level)
{
// Turn Level Indicator Red
}
else if (message.destinationName == /data/read/nozzle)

{
// Turn Nozzle Indicator Red
}
}
else if(message.payloadString == "OFF")
{

if(message.destinationName == /data/read/level)
{
// Turn Level Indicator Green
}
else if (message.destinationName == /data/read/nozzle)
{
// Turn Nozzle Indicator Green}}  }
```

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript. Are you getting a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

`message.destinationName` is string so wrap it up inside quotes. Like first one it should be `"/data/read/level"` instead of `/data/read/level`, same for others.

Answer (score 0):

First your syntax is wrong, second, correcting it depends on what you ultimately want to check.  I can't tell if you're trying to compare to the paths you've inserted or if you want to compare to the value stored in the location those paths lead to.

If you want to see if the object equals the path you're providing you want to do

```
if(message.destinationName == 'data/read/level'){...}
```

if you want to see if the object equals the value of what you have stored in that location you want to do

```
if(message.destinationName == data.read.level){...}
```

your `console.log()` is also a little off, for how you're trying to display the data you could just create an object inside the `console.log()` like this

```
console.log({
    topic: message.destinationName,
    payload: message.payloadString,
    qos: message.qos
});
```

it will render in the console as a regular data object like anything else instead of trying to concat strings in between each result trying to get the same output pretty much.  Hope this helps.